# Where are wireless or internet connection logs?

Tags: wireless, log

I want to go into a log file and see what happens when my Wi-fi drops, then take it elsewhere? Where can I find this?

Comment: You could find it on `/var/log/syslog` file.

Comment: That seems sensible. How do I mark this question as solved? Or link to the duplicate myself?

Comment: I think you can be able to delete this question.

Comment: So those two choices I mentioned are not available here?